# select entity with one child in entity framework for oracle

Tags: c#, entity-framework, odp.net

Following query throws 'Oracle 10.2.0.3.0 does not support APPLY ' exception

```
var q = _dbTaxObjects
    .Select(o => new TaxObjectItem()
    {
        MainAddress = o.MainAddress,
        Id = o.Id,
        ObjectName = o.ObjectName,
        State = o.State,
        LastCheck = o.Checks.OrderByDescending(ch => ch.EndDate).FirstOrDefault()
    });
```

I need to select taxObjects with one child (taxObjectCheck) that has max endDate (if exists).
The query is working well if I comment LastCheck assignment.

Comment: Here's some more information and some further links to read about avoiding the creation of the APPLY keyword by Entity Framework: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/207b0016-a848-4895-a2b3-890612072bbd/preventing-crossouter-apply-from-data-services?forum=adodotnetdataservices

Comment: From MSDN: The following are some typical scenarios that might lead to the presence of CROSS APPLY and/or OUTER APPLY operators in the output query:

    A correlated subquery with paging.

    An AnyElement over a correlated sub-query, or over a collection produced by navigation.

    LINQ queries that use grouping methods that accept an element selector.

    A query in which a CROSS APPLY or an OUTER APPLY is explicitly specified

    A query that has a DEREF construct over a REF construct.